# What form does 会いたくなる belong to?

Tags: grammar

I am confused with the word form 会いたくなる belongs to.

This phrase is found in this sentence:

> ひとりでいると 会いたくなるよ

So far, what I know:
会う: meet
会いたい: want to meet

But I don't know what is 会いたくなる and how this phrase is formed?

Answer (score 4):

> 「Verb in 連用形{れんようけい} (continuative form) + たくなる」

means:

> "to get the urge to (verb)"

You will keep encountering this pattern for as long as you study Japanese.

The verb 「なる」 always expresses a change of state; It is a key verb in the language.  I could not live one day without using 「なる」 at least 20 times just as an English-speaker could not live a day without using the verb "to get" at least 20 times.  20 would probably be an understatement, too.

Notice that both 「会い」 and 「たく」 are 連用形 of 「会う」 and 「たい」,  respectively.  連用形 is extremely important and that is why I have to say "連用形{れんようけい} (continuative form)" all the time here even if it takes me a long time to type all that each time.

So, the sentence in question means:

> "I get the urge to see you when I am alone."

Comment: To me, this is skipping a step. I would personally start with「Verb in 連用形{れんようけい} (continuative form) +たい」and then「Stem of い-adjective (i.e. without the い at the end) +くなる」(たい makes an い-adjective) because to me this 1) explains better what is going on with the morphemes, and 2) better picks up from what the OP has written.

Answer (score 2):

> 〜になる　〜くなる

expresses a change of state, as in becoming.

> 忙しくなる to become busy (忙しい)
>
> 綺麗になる to be clean/beautiful
>
> ヒーローになる to become a hero

In your example

> 会いたい　ー　会いた（い ー> くなる）

you say that you feel you are missing someone/thing, therefore you want to see/meet him/her/them/it.